# How to return JSON in swift from HTTPPost

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to iOS developing and need some help with JSON and what to be returning. I have the following function in my modal:

```
 func loginRequest(username: String, password: String, completionHandler: ((NSURLResponse!, JSON, NSError?) -> Void)) {
        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.URL = NSURL(string: ""correct post url"\(username)/\(password)")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse

            var json = JSON(data: data!)
            println(json)


        })

    }
```

This does successfully return the JSON if I print it inside this function. However, the following code in my view controller yields no errors but fails to return the JSON at all.

```
@IBAction func signIn(sender: UIButton) { 

 modal.loginRequest("Test", password: "Pass") { (response, json, error) -> Void in
        println(json)
        println("Hello")
        if (json != nil) {
                Do parsing stuff
           }
    }
```

In my `ViewController`, `json` does not return nil, it doesn't return at all. The code prints in from my modal but does not show in the VC. How am I calling the function wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't call the completion handler closure which is passed as param. If you want access the data however, you have to call the `completionHandler` closure. This is how your code should be:

```
func loginRequest(username: String, password: String, completionHandler: ((NSURLResponse!, JSON, NSError?) -> Void)) {
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: ""correct post url"\(username)/\(password)")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse

        var json = JSON(data: data!)
        println(json)

        // call the closure argument here, to pass the asynchrounsly retrieved vallues
        // back to the caller of loginRequest
        completionHandler(response, json, error)

    })

}
```

Comment: Ah that is an easy fix. I want to learn a little better how this is happening. Can you point me to a good place?

Comment: Yes of course: Check the [official library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) to learn more about closures.

When you've done reading it, try to right one or two of your own :)

Comment: Also, the overall thing is called asynchronous programming. You could also [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyluPwsPZ8c).